# How to pass class-validator @isArray when single item comes from query param

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to validate request with [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) if it's array.

inputs comes from query param with `/api/items?someTypes=this`

my request dto looks like this.

```
    (...)
    @IsArray()
    @IsEnum(SOMETHING, {each: true})
    readonly someTypes: keyof typeof SOMETHING[];
    (...)
```

when I give only one item, @IsArray gives validation error, saying it is not an array.

I want to make it array too when one item comes from query param, but I don't know how.

I know using `/api/items?someTypes[]=this` will pass validation.

but I want to know if there is another way to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field is an array and you want to perform validation of each item in the array you must pass a special `each: true` option to the `@IsEnum()` decorator.

```
import { IsArray, IsEnum } from 'class-validator';

enum SomeType {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

class SearchQuery {
  @IsArray()
  @IsEnum(SomeType, { each: true })
  types: SomeType[];
}


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  async search(@Query() searchQuery: SearchQuery): Promise<void> 
  { ... }
}
```

You can then perform a GET request to your endpoint using the following syntax.

```
?types[]=A&types[]=B&types[]=C
```

That works perfectly fine when you pass just one item.

```
?types[]=A
```

If you don't like this syntax and prefer `types=A,B,C` then you can combine `class-validator` with `class-tranformer`.

```
class SearchQuery {
  @IsArray()
  @IsEnum(SomeType, { each: true })
  @Transform(({ value }) =>
    value
      .trim()
      .split(',')
      .map((type) => SomeType[type]),
  )
  types: SomeType[];
}
```

Comment: solved with @Transform() decorator. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already set the `each` option, so you don't need to use `@IsArray`.
[validating-arrays](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-arrays)